# update the 'Null' value to the data time in to sql server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm using sql server and i update the date_time column to null .

Query is :

```
update table_name 
set date_col=Null 
where item=201 and job_code=3
```

when i exec the query in database it's working fine .

And pass the same query in vb.net it exec but the data_time column has to change minimum value like :'1/1900 12:00:00 AM'
how can able to update the record .
give the example of the update query

Comment: How are you executing it in vb.net?

Answer (score 1):

Your sample date format is incorrect. To update rows with lowest data value you can use

```
update table_name 
set date_col='1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM'
where item=201 and job_code=3
```

If your column data type is [dattime2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) then you can give date as minimum as '01/01/0001'

```
update table_name 
set date_col='1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM'
where item=201 and job_code=3
```